# Pinterest By Auto Upload Pins Using Python does not include title, description and link

Tags: python

the Script logs in, includes the image, but does not include the title, description, date and link and posts

font: https://github.com/maximedrn/pinterest-automatic-upload?tab=readme-ov-file